# Sort Datatable by both header rows

Tags: javascript, datatables

How to give the same sorting functionality to both header rows?
At the moment I can sort either by top("bSortCellsTop": true) or bottom row but not both.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karin/hov4wzzq/)

```
<table id="example" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>sort 2015</th><th>sort 2016</th></tr>
    <tr><th>sort 2012</th><th>sort 2013</th><th>sort 2014</th><th></th><th>  </th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>23</td><td>11</td><td>900</td><td>100</td><td>2358</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>45</td><td>410</td><td>1</td><td>531</td></tr>
    <tr><td>64</td><td>126</td><td>6310</td><td>85</td><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>86</td><td>524</td><td>520</td><td>65</td><td>68</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code for table header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use the code below to sort header by both top and bottom rows.

**JavaScript**:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    "orderCellsTop": true
});

$('#example').on('click', 'tr:eq(1) th', function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().find('th').index(this);    
    var cellTop = $(this).closest('thead').find('tr:eq(0) th:eq('+index +')');
    $(cellTop).trigger('click');
});
```

**CSS**:

```css
#example thead th {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Please note that the code above will work only if number of columns in each row is the same.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hov4wzzq/3/) for code and demonstration.